# String to date conversion in XSLT returns function not found

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to determine if the current date is between two other dates in XSLT/XPath. I found that xs:date(STRING) converts a date string to a date value and I can then compare with current-date().

My problem is while trying this out, I get an error saying the function does not exist. Nor does dateTime exists apparently. Here's my code with the namespaces I'm using.

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-functions/"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/">


        <xsl:if test = "fn:current-dateTime lt fn:date(EndDateActive)
                        and fn:current-dateTime gt fn:date(StartDateActive)">
```

The End and Start Date strings are formatted correctly afaik (yyyy-mm-dd) and I have tried the following options too, all of them tell me the function does not exist:

```
xs:date(EndDateActivate)
xsl:date(EndDateActivate)
fn:dateTime(EndDateActivate)
xs:dateTime(EndDateActivate)
xsl:dateTime(EndDateActivate)
```

Comment: XSLT 2 and later support the `xs:date`, `xs:dateTime` data types  and constructor functions of those names and date or dateTime functions like `current-dateTime`. However you either use those functions unprefixed e.g. `current-dateTime()` or you use them with a prefix declared for the right namespace which is the XPath 2 and later function namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions` e.g. `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`.

Comment: You have used the wrong namespace for your attempts to use `fn:current-dateTime` and also for `xs:date`, as the right namespace there is `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

- `fn:current-dateTime()` is a function. You are missing the `()`
- The `fn` namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions`, not `http://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-functions/`

  - In XSLT, you don't need to use the `fn:` namespace prefix. You could just use `current-dateTime()`
- The Schema namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`, not `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/` (remove the trailing `/`)
- You are attempting to compare `xs:dateTime` to `xs:date`

  - Rather than `current-dateTime()`, use `current-date()`

Make the following adjustments to your namespace declarations:

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

and to your `@test`:

```
<xsl:if test="fn:current-date() lt xs:date(EndDateActive)
          and fn:current-date() gt xs:date(StartDateActive)">
</xsl:if>
```